# await CLGeocoder.GeocodeAddressAsync never returns

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, async-await, core-location

I'm trying to test the accuracy of Apple's forward geocoding service to cover the rare case when the latitude/longitude we have on our data model is missing or invalid, but we still know the physical address. Monotouch provides `CLGeocoder.GeocodeAddress(String, CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)` and `GeocodeAddressAsync(String)` but when I call them the completionHandler is never called and the async method never returns.

Nothing in my application log indicates a problem and enclosing the call in a try-catch block didn't turn up any exceptions. Maps integration is enabled in the project options. Short of capturing network traffic (which is probably SSL anyway) I'm out of ideas.

Here's the code which loads placemarks and tries to geocode addresses:

```
    private void ReloadPlacemarks()
    {
        // list to hold any placemarks which come back with empty/invalid coordinates
        List<ServiceCallWrapper> geoList = new List<ServiceCallWrapper> ();

        mapView.ClearPlacemarks ();

        List<MKPlacemark> placemarks = new List<MKPlacemark>();
        if (serviceCallViewModel.ActiveServiceCall != null) {
            var serviceCall = serviceCallViewModel.ActiveServiceCall;
            if (serviceCall.dblLatitude != 0 && serviceCall.dblLongitude != 0) {
                placemarks.Add (serviceCall.ToPlacemark ());
            } else {
                // add it to the geocode list
                geoList.Add (serviceCall);
            }
        }

        foreach (var serviceCall in serviceCallViewModel.ServiceCalls) {
            if (serviceCall.dblLatitude != 0 && serviceCall.dblLongitude != 0) {
                placemarks.Add (serviceCall.ToPlacemark ());
            } else {
                //add it to the geocode list
                geoList.Add (serviceCall);
            }
        }

        if (placemarks.Count > 0) {
            mapView.AddPlacemarks (placemarks.ToArray ());
        }

        if (geoList.Count > 0) {

            // attempt to forward-geocode the street address
            foreach (ServiceCallWrapper s in geoList) {
                ServiceCallWrapper serviceCall = GeocodeServiceCallAddressAsync (s).Result;
                mapView.AddPlacemark (serviceCall.ToPlacemark());
            }
        }

    }

    private async Task<ServiceCallWrapper> GeocodeServiceCallAddressAsync(ServiceCallWrapper s)
    {
        CLGeocoder geo = new CLGeocoder ();
        String addr = s.address + " " + s.city + " " + s.state + " " + s.zip;
        Console.WriteLine ("Attempting forward geocode for service call UID: " + s.call_uid + " with address: " + addr);

                    //app hangs on this
        CLPlacemark[] result = await geo.GeocodeAddressAsync(addr);

                    //code updating latitude and longitude (omitted)

        return s;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
ServiceCallWrapper serviceCall = GeocodeServiceCallAddressAsync (s).Result;
```

By calling `Task<T>.Result`, you are causing a deadlock. I explain this fully [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), but the gist of it is that `await` will (by default) capture a "context" when it yields control, and will use that context to complete the `async` method. In this case, the "context" is the UI context. So, the UI thread is blocked (waiting on `Result`) when the response comes in, and the `async` method cannot continue because it's waiting to run on the UI thread.

The solution is to use `async` all the way. In other words, replace every `Task<T>.Result` and `Task.Wait` with `await`:

```
private async Task ReloadPlacemarksAsync()
{
  ...
  ServiceCallWrapper serviceCall = await GeocodeServiceCallAddressAsync (s);
  ...
}
```

Note that your `void ReloadPlacemarks` is now `Task ReloadPlacemarksAsync`, so this change affects your callers. `async` will "grow" through the codebase, and this is normal. For more information, see my [MSDN article on async best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).